# Правильность написания фразы

Tags: пунктуация

А о чем именно - увидите сами.

Comment: Ошибок нет. А в чем сомнения?

Answer (score 1):

***А о чем именно — увидите сами.***

Тире ставится в обязательном порядке.

Пояснение

Союз А является присоединительным, остальная часть  — это **сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП)** с придаточным изъяснительным.

**Тире ставится по следующим причинам:** 1) придаточное предложение неполное; 2) придаточное предложение находится перед главным (инверсированная позиция).

Таким образом, у нас **ДВА ФАКТОРА,** которые способствуют постановке тире. В этом случае надо четко обозначить **границу между частями предложения,** что и делается с помощью тире на письме и паузы в устной речи.

**Почему в этом предложении надо поставить тире с точки зрения интонации**

**А о чЁм именно — увидите сами.**  Знаки препинания обозначают грамматику и интонацию предложения. В данном случае тире обозначает не только паузу, но **и логическое ударение, которое падает на вопросительное слово.**

**Розенталь (условия постановки тире в СПП)**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Answer (score 0):

Фраза написана нормативно, хотя, как правило, предложения, вводимые относительными местоимениями, считаются придаточными и, следовательно, должны обособляться запятой. Тире здесь необходимо для постановки логического ударения, подчёркивающего важность последующего события. Очень часто такие сочетания используются в художественной литературе, кстати.